# Trailing return type array

Tags: c++, arrays, types, return, trailing

```
auto function(int i) -> int(*)[10]{

}
```

Can anyone help me how to return a pointer to array of 10 integers using trailing return type? Any example will be helpful.

Comment: Haven't you done exactly that in this post?

Comment: I don't know how return works inside a function body. little bit confused about the structure.

Comment: If you want a pointer to a `T`, make a `T` and take its address... or take `nullptr` and convert it to `T*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t sz = 10;

auto func(int i) -> int(*)[sz] /// returns a pointer to an array of ten ints
{
static int arr[sz];

for (size_t i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
    arr[i] = i;

return &arr;
}

int main()
{
int i = 2;
int (*p)[sz] = func(i); /// points to an array of ten ints which funct returns which is arr array

for (size_t ind = 0; ind != sz; ++ind) /// displays the values
    std::cout << (*p)[ind] << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

> auto function (int i) -> int(*)[sz]

- this means that a function name funct have a parameters of int that accepts
  an int argument and  return a pointer to an array of 10 ints which means 
  that we pointed every int element in an array of ten int. trailing return    types are used for to read easily

to return a pointer to an array of ten int

> int i = 2;
>     int (*p)[sz] = funct(i);

- which means (*p)[sz] will pointed an array of 10 ints that a func function 
  returns which is arr array and displays the values using loop

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care whether your return value is dereferenceable (and you didn't specify that), the following will "return a pointer to an array of 10 integers":

```
auto function(int i) -> int(*)[10]
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: How can assign i to all 10 integer values and return values of array and print it in main function ?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to decide where the integers will be stored, how they'll be "shared", and whether the caller or callee is responsible for their lifetime.

Options include...

1) returning a pointer to newly dynamically allocated memory:

```
auto function(int i) -> int(*)[10] {
    int* p = new int[10];
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 39;
    ...
    p[9] = -3;
    return (int(*)[10])p;
}

// BTW it's usually cleaner (avoiding the ugly cast above) to handle
// arrays via a pointer (but you do lose the compile-time knowledge of
// array extent, which can be used e.g. by templates)
int* function(int i) {
    int* p = ...new and assign as above...
    return p;
}

// either way - the caller has to do the same thing...

void caller()
{
    int (*p)[10] = function();
    std::cout << p[0] + p[9] << '\n';
    delete[] p;
}
```

Note that 99% of the time returning either a `std::vector<int>` or a `std::array<int, 10>` is a better idea, and that 99% of the remaining time it's better to return a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` which the caller can move to their own variable, which will `delete[]` the data as it is destroyed by going out of scope or - for member variables - destruction of containing object.

2) returning a pointer to a `function()`-local `static` array (which will be overwritten each time `function` is called, such that old returned pointers will see the updated values and there could be race conditions in multithreaded code):

```
auto function(int i) -> int(*)[10]{
    static int a[10] { 1, 39, ..., -3 };
    return &a;
}
```

The caller calls this the same way, but ***must not*** call `delete[]`.

Comment: `int (*p)[10] = new int[10];` doesn't compile

Comment: The return type doesn't match the type of the returned object in the first example. And you need to return the address of the static array (`return &a`).

Comment: Array types are very tricky to handle dynamically. Plain `new` is a pain (as you've discovered), placement-`new` is entirely impossible, and allocators can't create them. The new `make_shared` for arrays is a hack at best.